# "if he resigned" VS "if he resign"

Tags: word-difference

I came across this sentence:

> 1. If he **resigned** it **would be** tantamount to admitting that he was guilty.

I am wondering whether he resigned or not. Would it be possbile to phrase like this

> 2. If he **resign** it **will be** tantamount to admitting that he was guilty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because your subject and verb don't agree and you haven't changed all of the verb tenses throughout the sentence.

You could say:

> If he **resigns** it **will be** tantamount to admitting that he **is** guilty.